# How do I use an if statement to run except when something else has happened?

Tags: java, if-statement, bluej

I am using Java to run balls around a box. By using this piece of code it bounces off the edges.

```
if (y >= borderBottom)
{
  y = border;
  speedOfY = -speedofY;
}
```

I have a hole in the box of balls. If the ball hits the hole I would like it to continue through the gap.

I want the if statement to run until:

- it's between two points on x (the hole)
- and at the border bottom on the y axis (the side of the hole).

How can I make this happen? I know I need to use simulation.pauseSimulation() but I don't know how to get the balls to stop specifically when it's between the two points and when it's at the border bottom, thanks!

I have tried using the previous statement with this afterwards,

```js
if(y >= borderBottom && (x < 275) && (x > 325>))
  simulation.pauseSimulation()
```

but I have played around and the simulation has ignored the whole bottom border and at one point all the objects flashed.

Comment: Keep track of the previous ball position and if you detect the ball has just hit the bottom, check if the strait line between the two ball positions crosses the border segment?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: @bipll I have used 

if (y >= borderBottom && (x < 275) && (x > 325>))
  simulation.pauseSimulation() 

but the issue is that I need this statement to override the other statement if all conditions are met. Is this possible?

Comment: hmmm... `x` can't be both _less_ than 275 **and** _greater_ than 325 — are you sure you don't have your values reversed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to know the bottom and top coordinates of the hole.
Afterwards, you can simply write:

```
if ( y >= borderBottom || ( y < holeBottom && y > holeTop ) ) {
    Simulation.pauseSimulation();
    //You can pause simulation or do anything you prefer
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be a good time to learn about logical operators (&&, &, ||, |, !, ^). Specifically in this case:

```
if (Condition A && Condition B)
{
   //Do something 
}
```

You could also use:

```
if(Condition A || Condition B)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Probably OR as well.